# Novel for teens about a magic stone and people who gain powers from it

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

It was a book based on a magic stone which had powers and shone sometimes. The story starts with a young boy who finds one piece of it and troubles start coming to him. Some people are looking for the stone (the villains). Then, he meets his best friend, who is older than him and knows a lot about forests. He tells him all about the secret of stone and they both have to leave the city.

As they are running, they find people who have similar powers by means of the same stone. One of them is an old man, one is a girl who worked at a salon, and maybe one was another boy. They are all running in the woods and different cities, but they can't call anybody at home because they are being traced.

They have very little money left, and in the end they get caught by the police, but before surrendering they realize the real reason for the stone. There was a ship with soldiers which had sunk a few days back, and nobody could save them, this day being their last day to save them.

So finally those 5 were taken near that drowning spot through deck. Then they all held hands and used their powers of the stone together. There was a hurricane in the water and then suddenly it became hollow where the ship was drowning and people took it out and then they released the spell. It made them exhausted and with no power. Then they all submitted their stones. But that man took the young hero on the side and said to remember that, on the same day next year, maybe the powers can come back to him.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.